# Python lognorm.cdf vs. formula based implementation not matching

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, distribution

Okay I am converting the `scipy.stats.lognorm.cdf` function over to a Cython function and using the formula here: http://www.cs.unitn.it/~taufer/SR/P-LN.pdf as 1/2 + 1/2* erf((ln(x)-mu)/sigma*sqrt(2). The results don't match, despite many other references to the same function online. EDIT: just fixed, only had to do np.log(mu) 2x ... Fixed code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import lognorm
from scipy.special import erf

def lognormcdf(x, mu, sigma):
    return 0.5 + 0.5*erf((np.log(x)-np.log(mu))/(np.sqrt(2.0)*sigma))

mu = 3.85
sigma = 0.346
x = [-9.997137267734412802e-01,-9.984919506395958377e-01,-9.962951347331251428e-01,-9.931249370374434227e-01,-9.889843952429917540e-01,-9.838775407060570410e-01,-9.778093584869183008e-01,-9.707857757637063933e-01,-9.628136542558155542e-01,-9.539007829254917414e-01,-9.440558701362560257e-01,-9.332885350430795146e-01,-9.216092981453339883e-01,-9.090295709825296777e-01,-8.955616449707269888e-01,-8.812186793850184108e-01,-8.660146884971646752e-01,-8.499645278795913139e-01,-8.330838798884008245e-01,-8.153892383391762033e-01,-7.968978923903144995e-01,-7.776279096494954635e-01,-7.575981185197071532e-01,-7.368280898020207470e-01,-7.153381175730564312e-01,-6.931491993558019926e-01,-6.702830156031409636e-01,-6.467619085141292912e-01,-6.226088602037077591e-01,-5.978474702471787694e-01,-5.725019326213811599e-01,-5.465970120650941455e-01,-5.201580198817630230e-01,-4.932107892081909473e-01,-4.657816497733580086e-01,-4.378974021720314913e-01,-4.095852916783015440e-01,-3.808729816246299582e-01,-3.517885263724216949e-01,-3.223603439005291449e-01,-2.926171880384719759e-01,-2.625881203715034751e-01,-2.323024818449739570e-01,-2.017898640957360157e-01,-1.710800805386032686e-01,-1.402031372361139672e-01,-1.091892035800611088e-01,-7.806858281343663497e-02,-4.687168242159163445e-02,-1.562898442154308370e-02,1.562898442154308370e-02,4.687168242159163445e-02,7.806858281343663497e-02,1.091892035800611088e-01,1.402031372361139672e-01,1.710800805386032686e-01,.017898640957360157e-01,2.323024818449739570e-01,2.625881203715034751e-01,2.926171880384719759e-01,3.223603439005291449e-01,3.517885263724216949e-01,3.808729816246299582e-01,4.095852916783015440e-01,4.378974021720314913e-01,4.657816497733580086e-01,4.932107892081909473e-01,5.201580198817630230e-01,5.465970120650941455e-01,5.725019326213811599e-01,5.978474702471787694e-01,6.226088602037077591e-01,6.467619085141292912e-01,6.702830156031409636e-01,6.931491993558019926e-01,7.153381175730564312e-01,7.368280898020207470e-01,7.575981185197071532e-01,7.776279096494954635e-01,7.968978923903144995e-01,8.153892383391762033e-01,8.330838798884008245e-01,8.499645278795913139e-01,8.660146884971646752e-01,8.812186793850184108e-01,8.955616449707269888e-01,9.090295709825296777e-01,9.216092981453339883e-01,9.332885350430795146e-01,9.440558701362560257e-01,9.539007829254917414e-01,9.628136542558155542e-01,9.707857757637063933e-01,9.778093584869183008e-01,9.838775407060570410e-01,9.889843952429917540e-01,9.931249370374434227e-01,9.962951347331251428e-01,9.984919506395958377e-01,9.997137267734412802e-01]
mycdf = lognormcdf(x, np.log(mu), sigma)
scipycdf = lognorm.cdf(x, scale=np.log(mu), s=sigma)

# This line comparing the Scipy function and mine displays the results below
np.sum(np.nan_to_num(mycdf)-scipycdf)
```

Results:

```
1.2011928779531548e-15
```

Comment: erf has sqrt(pi) in the numerator and the log-normal cdf has sqrt(2pi).

Comment: @kpie I have the lognorm pdf that uses the sqrt(2pi) that works, but I don't see it being used in the cdf formula.

Comment: Matt, is there still a problem?

Comment: No for some unknown reason despite the formulas it had to be log(mu) 2x

Comment: Well, then write an answer (you can answer your own question), and I'll endorse it and we will move on...

Comment: @Severin I posted the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original post was edited to reflect the correct formula.

```
def lognormcdf(x, mu, sigma):
    return 0.5 + 0.5*erf((np.log(x)-np.log(mu))/(np.sqrt(2.0)*sigma))
```

Pass `np.log(mu)` in for `mu` and it works.